# Error in example democracy contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I get this error when I try to paste the [democracy](https://www.ethereum.org/dao) contract code in solidity:

```
Unused local variable
        Member m = members[id];
```

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit:** I hadn't realised the Wallet treats warnings as errors.)

This is shown as a `Warning` in [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity), rather than an `Error` - it shouldn't stop the contract from compiling. If you're using the Ethereum Wallet, the unused variable stops the contract being deployed.

---

However... The contract code on that page seems to have changed at some point. That block of code used to look like this:

```
function changeMembership(address targetMember, bool canVote, string memberName) onlyOwner {
        uint id;
        if (memberId[targetMember] == 0) {
           memberId[targetMember] = members.length;
           id = members.length++;
           members[id] = Member({member: targetMember, canVote: canVote, memberSince: now, name: memberName});
        } else {
            id = memberId[targetMember];
            Member m = members[id];
            m.canVote = canVote;
        }

        MembershipChanged(targetMember, canVote);

    }
```

Where the function was called `changeMembership()`, and we passed in the `canVote` boolean. Instead we now have `addMember()` and `removeMember()`, but it seems the `Member M` line has been left behind.

I'd recommend changing the code from this:

```
   /*make member*/
    function addMember(address targetMember, string memberName) onlyOwner {
        uint id;
        if (memberId[targetMember] == 0) {
           memberId[targetMember] = members.length;
           id = members.length++;
           members[id] = Member({member: targetMember, memberSince: now, name: memberName});
        } else {
            id = memberId[targetMember];
            Member m = members[id];
        }

        MembershipChanged(targetMember, true);
    }
```

...to the following:

```
function addMember(address targetMember, string memberName) onlyOwner {
    uint id;
    if (memberId[targetMember] == 0) {
        memberId[targetMember] = members.length;
        id = members.length++;
        members[id] = Member({member: targetMember, memberSince: now, name: memberName});
        MembershipChanged(targetMember, true);
    }
}
```

Remember, these code samples are only examples - you shouldn't rely on them for correctness, nor should you send the `payable` functions anything of real value until you're absolutely certain you know how it all works.

Comment: If you use the ethereum wallet it doesn't let you deploy the contract

Comment: [This is how it looks if there is no error](http://imgur.com/a/sUB9V). With the error [the option to deploy is gone](http://imgur.com/a/WiWIv)

Comment: Also could you clarify which part of the contract your new code replaces. I assumed from after `uint id` until the final `}` from the excerpt you copied. I tried that and the error does go away

Comment: Okay, the Ethereum Wallet must have more stringent checks than Remix. The Wallet must treat a `Warning` as an `Error`. I've updated my answer to clarify which bit of code to change. (But yes, you are correct.)